# Хочу создать умного бота для телеграмма через dialogflow

Tags: telegram, dialogflow

Собственно есть dialogflow и телеграмм. Хотелось бы узнать, есть ли способ, чтоб dialogflow перехватывал новых пользователей чата, и приветствовал их? Пока придумываю костыли, но чет не идет.

Answer (score 1):

не знаю разрешены ли тут ссылки, но хабре есть статья по данной теме, введи в поиск "[Обучаемый Telegram чат-бот с ИИ в 30 строчек кода на Python](https://habr.com/ru/post/346606/)"

Comment: Ссылки разрешены при условии, что вы основное из ссылки внесли прямо в тело ответа. Воспользуйтесь кнопкой  [править](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/343932).